If A is a Lebesgue Measurable set, find measure of reflection
Suppose we have a set $A \subset \Bbb{R^2}$ that is Lebesgue measurable.
Now define $B$ = {$(x,-y) : (x,y) \in A$). We want to find the Lebesgue Measure of B
It’s seems to me that $B$ has the same Lebesgue Measure than $A$, but I need help to make my “proof” formal enough :
$\lambda(A)^* $ = inf{$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}v(I_n) : A \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$}, with $I_n$ open. Take precisely the $I_n$’s such that the sum of  the areas of the squares is the infimum of the set.
If $I_n = (a,b)$ with $a_1 \leq a \leq a_2$ ; $b_1 \leq b \leq b_2$,  if we make $I_n’ = (a,-b)$ with $a_1 \leq a \leq a_2$ ; $-b_2 \leq -b \leq -b_1$ then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n’$ is a cover of $B$ (how can I show this?)
Since any square $(c,d)$ in $\Bbb{R^2}$ has the same area that $(c,-d)$, $\lambda (A) = \lambda (B)$.
It’s my idea correct? How can I show that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n’$ is a cover of $B$? Is there any other suggerencr to make this more rigorous?
Thanks.

You are overthinking this. If $C$ is any cover of $A$ then the reflections of the sets in $C$ will cover the reflection of $A$.

If $(x,y)\in B$, then $(x,-y)\in A$. There exists $n$ such that $(x,-y)\in I_n$, so $(x,y)\in I_n'$. Then $B\subset\bigcup_n I_n'$. You can do this the other way around, so the map $\gamma:(x,y)\longmapsto (x,-y)$ induces a bijection between covers of $A$ and $B$. As you said, $\lambda(\gamma(I_n))=\lambda(I_n)$, so for both $\lambda^*(A)$ and $\lambda^*(B)$ we are taking infimum over the same set of numbers; hence $\lambda^*(A)=\lambda^*(B)$.
You have that $A$ is measurable by hypothesis, and $\gamma$ is a continuous bijection such that $\lambda^*\circ\gamma=\lambda^*$. Then, for any $S\subset\mathbb R^2$,
\begin{align}
\lambda^*(B\cap S)+\lambda^*(B\cap S^c)&=\lambda^*(\gamma(A)\cap S)+\lambda^*(\gamma(A)\cap S^c)\\[0.2cm]
&=\lambda^*(\gamma(A\cap\gamma^{-1}(S)))+\lambda^*(\gamma(A\cap\gamma^{-1}(S)^c)\\[0.2cm]
&=\lambda^*(A\cap\gamma^{-1}(S))+\lambda^*(A\cap\gamma^{-1}(S)^c)\\[0.2cm]
&=\lambda^*(A)=\lambda^*(B).
\end{align}
So $B$ is measurable, and $\lambda(B)=\lambda(A)$.
